# Mapping Tables for Parcel IDs

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a residential real estate database in MS ACCESS.  I currently have residential property’s tagged by parcel ID’s.  I am trying to run a query to pull in multiple sales data from various tables.  I need to somehow map in street mapping to only pull data for all property’s within a mile radius.  Can anyone explain to me how I can find this mapping?   I can program this in access – I just can’t locate the mapping for this project.
Thanks, 
Derrick

PS - location - US, Indiana

Answer (score 2):

Here are my two ideas:

1. Most county Auditor Departments have a parcel GIS layer (that is in a mapable format).  You could contact this department to see if you can obtain this layer, then do a table join based on common parcel ID field to your table.
2. If you database has address information you could geocode that against the [U.S Census Bureau TIGER Street Centerline](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/shp.html) data.

Mapping may be done in open source GIS software application such as [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

Answer (score 0):

A quick search yielded a few likely results.

1. [IndianaMap.org](http://www.indianamap.org/resources.php):  This should probably be your first choice as it is funded by a group of providers throughout the state.  It has links to the [Indiana Spatial Data Portal](http://www.indiana.edu/~gisdata/) at Indiana University, as well as a list of local data mapping websites.
2. [Indiana County-based GIS Data CD-rom](http://www.extension.purdue.edu/waterquality/Indiana%20County-Based%20GIS%20Data.htm):  This is a CD of data clipped at a buffer in the county around Purdue University.  It is available for $9, which could be a bargain depending on the extent.

These, along with the ideas posted by @artwork21 should give you enough to do a buffer to limit your data.

For future reference, these results all came from a web search for "indiana gis data".  The links shown were all in the top 10 results.